# Uso de While en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while, python-requests

Estoy aprendiendo a programar con Python y tengo algunas dudas hasta el momento:

Sobre el uso del While:

Empecé a escribir este código para practicar el uso del While. Básicamente es un programa que solicita elegir una modalidad (jugador o equipo, representados con las letras j o J para jugador y e o E para equipo), para luego proceder a solicitar datos para al final realizar un cálculo básico.

Creo que estoy implementando mal el While en el código porque, anque elija una de las 4 opciones permitidas (j, J, e, E), luego de teclear una de las dos letras aparece el mensaje "Has introducido una modalidad incorrecta, vuelve a intentarlo." y pienso que debería aparecer si ingreso cualquier caracter que no sea j, J, e o E. Luego al elegir por sgunda vez y colocar j o J, si entra en el if selectMode == "j" or "J" y empieza a solicitar los datos del jugador.
Si se elige e o E (por segunda vez luego de que aparece el mensaje "Has introducido una modalidad incorrecta, vuelve a intentarlo." ) automáticamente entra al  if selectMode == "j" or "J" y no al elif selectMode == "e" or "E".

Agradecido por el apoyo que puedan brindar.

````
selectMode=(input(str("Introduzca modalidad (pulse J para jugador o E para equipo): ")))

while selectMode != "j" or selectMode != "J" or selectMode != "e" or selectMode != "E":
    print("Has introducido una modalidad incorrecta, vuelve a intentarlo.")
    selectMode=(input(str("Introduzca modalidad (jugador o equipo): ")))
      
    if selectMode == "j" or "J":
        
        playerName=input("Introduce el nombre del jugador: ")
        
        playerGames=int(input("Introduce los partidos jugados: "))

        playerGoals=int(input("Introduce la cantidad de goles marcados: "))

        playerAvgGol=playerGoals/playerGames    #Se pude usar la función round(x). Revisar info sobre función round()

        print("El avg gol del jugador " + str(playerName) + " es de " + str(playerAvgGol) + " goles por partido.")
        
        print("El programa de pruebas a culminado.")

        break
    
    elif selectMode == "e" or "E":
    
        teamName=(input("Introduce el nombre del equipo: "))

        teamGames=(int(input("Introduce la cantidad de partidos jugados: ")))
        
        teamGoals=(int(input("Introduce la cantidad de goles marcados: ")))
        
        teamGoalAverage=teamGoals/teamGames

        print("El avg gol del equipo " + str(teamName) + " es " + str(teamGoalAverage))

        print("El programa de pruebas a culminado.")

        break deportivas.")

selectMode=(input(str("Introduzca modalidad (pulse J para jugador o E para equipo): ")))

while selectMode != "j" or selectMode != "J" or selectMode != "e" or selectMode != "E":
    print("Has introducido una modalidad incorrecta, vuelve a intentarlo.")
    selectMode=(input(str("Introduzca modalidad (jugador o equipo): ")))
      
    if selectMode == "j" or "J":
        
        playerName=input("Introduce el nombre del jugador: ")
        
        playerGames=int(input("Introduce los partidos jugados: "))

        playerGoals=int(input("Introduce la cantidad de goles marcados: "))

        playerAvgGol=playerGoals/playerGames    #Se pude usar la función round(x). Revisar info sobre función round()

        print("El avg gol del jugador " + str(playerName) + " es de " + str(playerAvgGol) + " goles por partido.")
        
        print("El programa de pruebas a culminado.")

        break
    
    elif selectMode == "e" or "E":
    
        teamName=(input("Introduce el nombre del equipo: "))

        teamGames=(int(input("Introduce la cantidad de partidos jugados: ")))
        
        teamGoals=(int(input("Introduce la cantidad de goles marcados: ")))
        
        teamGoalAverage=teamGoals/teamGames

        print("El avg gol del equipo " + str(teamName) + " es " + str(teamGoalAverage))

        print("El programa de pruebas a culminado.")

        break```
````

Answer (score 3):

Este `if` no hace lo que piensas:

```
if selectMode == "j" or "J":
```

Este `if` se ejecuta siempre, pues tiene dos expresiones lógicas, una de las cuales es siempre `True`:

- `selectMode == "j"` es la primera.
- `"J"` es la segunda.
  En Python todo tiene un valor `True` o `False`. En particular, una cadena vacía es `False`, pero si tiene al menos un carácter, es `True`. Por tanto, el `if` queda reducido a

  if selectMode == "j" or True:

que se puede reducir a

```
if True:
```

lo que definitivamente no es lo que quieres.

**Solución**

Cambia los `if` (y otras expresiones lógicas) para hacer explicita las comparaciones:

```
if selectMode == "j" or selectMode == "J":
```

o, más breve:

```
if selectMode in "jJ":
```

También puedes simplificar aqui:

```
while selectMode != "j" or selectMode != "J" or selectMode != "e" or selectMode != "E":
```

usando

```
while selectMode not in "jeJE":
```

Comment: jo del "jeJE" al final tiene su coña....

Comment: Gracias. Hice los cambios al código tomando en cuenta tus observaciones. Al momento de correr el código por primera vez, cuando debes elegir la modalidad debes colocar eE o jJ, porque si solo se coloca j, J, e o E sale del programa automáticamente.
Aún así, colocando eE o jJ, por primera vez, también indica que has colocado una modalidad incorrecta (lo mismo que sucedía con el primer código que publiqué). Luego de elegir por segunda vez eE o jJ sí se cumple uno de los if y el programa corre hasta el final. Voy a intentar sacando el if y el elif del while.

Answer (score 0):

```
Si a parte del 'or' que es este caso de beser  'and', porque si no por una condicion entrqa en el bucle y no saldrias nunca, la indentacion de los condicionales estaban dentro del ciclo while y debes sacarlos porque el while así lo requiere en tu código. y si para las mayusculas y minúsculas utlilizas el método lower() por ejemplo te ahorras un poco de de código.


print("Programa de prueba para estadísticas deportivas.")

selectMode=(input("Introduzca modalidad (pulse J para jugador o E para equipo): "))
while selectMode.lower()!='j' and selectMode.lower()!='e':
  print("Has introducido una modalidad incorrecta, vuelve a intentarlo.")
  selectMode=(input("Introduzca modalidad (jugador o equipo): "))

if selectMode.lower() == "j":


  playerName=input("Introduce el nombre del jugador: ")

  playerGames=int(input("Introduce los partidos jugados: "))

  playerGoals=int(input("Introduce la cantidad de goles marcados: "))

  playerAvgGol=playerGoals/playerGames    #Se pude usar la función round(x). Revisar info sobre función round()

  print("El avg gol del jugador " + str(playerName) + " es de " + str(playerAvgGol) + " goles por partido.")

  print("El programa de pruebas a culminado.")


elif selectMode.lower() == "e":

  teamName=(input("Introduce el nombre del equipo: "))

  teamGames=(int(input("Introduce la cantidad de partidos jugados: ")))

  teamGoals=(int(input("Introduce la cantidad de goles marcados: ")))

  teamGoalAverage=teamGoals/teamGames

  print("El avg gol del equipo " + str(teamName) + " es " + str(teamGoalAverage))

  print("El programa de pruebas a culminado.")
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por las sugerencias. En efecto, sacando el if y el elif del bucle, cambiando los or por and y usando la función lower(), el programa corrió de manera correcta.

Comment: Luego de haber podido mejorar el código me queda algunas dudas: 
Luego de cambiar los or por and, usar la función lower(), pero dejando el if y el elif dentro del While,
¿Por qué al elegir j o e el progama termina de correr? y al colocar por primera vez cualquier otro caracter el programa indica que colocaste una modalidad incorrecta (se ejecuta el while) pero al colocar por segunda vez j o e el programa si entra en el if o el elif.